# Can't install geany debugger plugin

Tags: debugging, geany

Using Ubuntu 14.04.   I installed geany-1.27 successfully, and then tried to install geany-plugins-1.27, because debugger plugin is included
When I run ./configure, I see

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether UID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking whether GID '1000' is supported by ustar format... yes
checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... -std=gnu99
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc -std=gnu99... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc -std=gnu99 object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu99 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc -std=gnu99 linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking whether NLS is requested... yes
checking for intltool >= 0.35.0... 0.50.2 found
checking for intltool-update... /usr/bin/intltool-update
checking for intltool-merge... /usr/bin/intltool-merge
checking for intltool-extract... /usr/bin/intltool-extract
checking for xgettext... /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.18.2
checking for XML::Parser... ok
checking locale.h usability... yes
checking locale.h presence... yes
checking for locale.h... yes
checking for LC_MESSAGES... yes
checking libintl.h usability... yes
checking libintl.h presence... yes
checking for libintl.h... yes
checking for ngettext in libc... yes
checking for dgettext in libc... yes
checking for bind_textdomain_codeset... yes
checking for msgfmt... (cached) /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for dcgettext... yes
checking if msgfmt accepts -c... yes
checking for gmsgfmt... (cached) /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for xgettext... (cached) /usr/bin/xgettext
checking for catalogs to be installed...  be ca da de es fr gl it ja kk nl pt pt_BR ru tr zh_CN
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for GEANY... yes
checking for CHECK... no
checking for cppcheck... NONE
checking for the C compiler flag to treat warnings as errors... -Werror
checking whether the C compiler understands -Wall... yes
checking whether the C compiler understands -Wimplicit-function-declaration... yes
checking whether the C compiler understands -Wmissing-parameter-type... yes
checking whether the C compiler understands -Wold-style-declaration... yes
checking whether the C compiler understands -Wpointer-arith... yes
checking whether the C compiler understands -Wshadow... yes
checking whether the C compiler understands -Wundef... yes
checking whether the C compiler understands -Wwrite-strings... yes
checking whether the linker understands -Wl,-z,defs... yes
checking for AUTOCLOSE... yes
checking for AUTOMARK... yes
checking for COMMANDER... yes
checking whether the GTK version in use is compatible with plugin Debugger... yes
checking for VTE... no
checking util.h usability... no
checking util.h presence... no
checking for util.h... no
checking pty.h usability... yes
checking pty.h presence... yes
checking for pty.h... yes
checking libutil.h usability... no
checking libutil.h presence... no
checking for libutil.h... no
checking for DEFINEFORMAT... yes
checking for glib-genmarshal... /usr/bin/glib-genmarshal
checking for glib-mkenums... /usr/bin/glib-mkenums
checking whether the GTK version in use is compatible with plugin devhelp... yes
checking for DEVHELP... no
checking whether the GTK version in use is compatible with plugin GeanyDoc... yes
checking for GEANYGENDOC... no
checking for rst2html... no
checking whether the GTK version in use is compatible with plugin GeanyLaTeX... yes
checking for LUA... no
checking whether the GTK version in use is compatible with plugin GeanyMacro... yes
checking whether the GTK version in use is compatible with plugin GeanyNumberedBookmarks... yes
checking whether the GTK version in use is compatible with plugin GeanyPrj... yes
checking whether the GTK version in use is compatible with plugin Geanypy... yes
checking for PYGTK... no
checking for GTKSPELL... no
checking for gpgme-config... no
checking for GPGME - version >= 0.4.2... no
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking for GENIUSPASTE... no
checking for GITCHANGEBAR... no
checking for library containing mkd_compile... no
checking for MARKDOWN... no
checking for valac... valac
checking whether the vala compiler is compatible with multiterm... no
checking for GLIB... yes
checking for LIBXML... no
checking whether the GTK version in use is compatible with plugin Scope... yes
checking for VTE... no
checking for util.h... (cached) no
checking for pty.h... (cached) yes
checking for libutil.h... (cached) no
checking for ENCHANT... no
checking for ENCHANT... no
checking for creat... yes
checking for GIO... yes
checking for UPDATECHECKER... no
checking for glib-mkenums... (cached) /usr/bin/glib-mkenums
checking for WEBHELPER... no
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating addons/Makefile
config.status: creating addons/src/Makefile
config.status: creating autoclose/Makefile
config.status: creating autoclose/src/Makefile
config.status: creating automark/Makefile
config.status: creating automark/src/Makefile
config.status: creating codenav/Makefile
config.status: creating codenav/src/Makefile
config.status: creating commander/Makefile
config.status: creating commander/src/Makefile
config.status: creating debugger/Makefile
config.status: creating debugger/src/Makefile
config.status: creating debugger/img/Makefile
config.status: creating defineformat/Makefile
config.status: creating defineformat/src/Makefile
config.status: creating devhelp/Makefile
config.status: creating devhelp/devhelp/Makefile
config.status: creating devhelp/src/Makefile
config.status: creating devhelp/data/Makefile
config.status: creating geanyctags/Makefile
config.status: creating geanyctags/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geanydoc/Makefile
config.status: creating geanydoc/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geanydoc/tests/Makefile
config.status: creating geanyextrasel/Makefile
config.status: creating geanyextrasel/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geanygendoc/Makefile
config.status: creating geanygendoc/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geanygendoc/data/Makefile
config.status: creating geanygendoc/data/filetypes/Makefile
config.status: creating geanygendoc/docs/Makefile
config.status: creating geanyinsertnum/Makefile
config.status: creating geanyinsertnum/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geanylatex/Makefile
config.status: creating geanylatex/doc/Makefile
config.status: creating geanylatex/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geanylipsum/Makefile
config.status: creating geanylipsum/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geanylua/examples/edit/Makefile
config.status: creating geanylua/examples/scripting/Makefile
config.status: creating geanylua/examples/info/Makefile
config.status: creating geanylua/examples/work/Makefile
config.status: creating geanylua/examples/dialogs/Makefile
config.status: creating geanylua/examples/Makefile
config.status: creating geanylua/docs/Makefile
config.status: creating geanylua/Makefile
config.status: creating geanymacro/Makefile
config.status: creating geanymacro/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geanyminiscript/Makefile
config.status: creating geanyminiscript/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geanynumberedbookmarks/Makefile
config.status: creating geanynumberedbookmarks/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geanyprj/Makefile
config.status: creating geanyprj/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geanypy/Makefile
config.status: creating geanypy/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geanypy/geany/Makefile
config.status: creating geanypy/plugins/Makefile
config.status: creating geanysendmail/Makefile
config.status: creating geanysendmail/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geanyvc/Makefile
config.status: creating geanyvc/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geanypg/Makefile
config.status: creating geanypg/src/Makefile
config.status: creating geniuspaste/Makefile
config.status: creating geniuspaste/data/Makefile
config.status: creating geniuspaste/src/Makefile
config.status: creating git-changebar/Makefile
config.status: creating git-changebar/data/Makefile
config.status: creating git-changebar/src/Makefile
config.status: creating lineoperations/Makefile
config.status: creating lineoperations/src/Makefile
config.status: creating markdown/Makefile
config.status: creating markdown/src/Makefile
config.status: creating markdown/docs/Makefile
config.status: creating markdown/peg-markdown/Makefile
config.status: creating markdown/peg-markdown/peg-0.1.9/Makefile
config.status: creating multiterm/Makefile
config.status: creating multiterm/src/Makefile
config.status: creating overview/Makefile
config.status: creating overview/data/Makefile
config.status: creating overview/overview/Makefile
config.status: creating pairtaghighlighter/Makefile
config.status: creating pairtaghighlighter/src/Makefile
config.status: creating pohelper/Makefile
config.status: creating pohelper/data/Makefile
config.status: creating pohelper/src/Makefile
config.status: creating pretty-printer/Makefile
config.status: creating pretty-printer/src/Makefile
config.status: creating projectorganizer/Makefile
config.status: creating projectorganizer/src/Makefile
config.status: creating projectorganizer/icons/Makefile
config.status: creating scope/Makefile
config.status: creating scope/data/Makefile
config.status: creating scope/docs/Makefile
config.status: creating scope/src/Makefile
config.status: creating shiftcolumn/Makefile
config.status: creating shiftcolumn/src/Makefile
config.status: creating spellcheck/Makefile
config.status: creating spellcheck/src/Makefile
config.status: creating treebrowser/Makefile
config.status: creating treebrowser/src/Makefile
config.status: creating tableconvert/Makefile
config.status: creating tableconvert/src/Makefile
config.status: creating updatechecker/Makefile
config.status: creating updatechecker/src/Makefile
config.status: creating webhelper/Makefile
config.status: creating webhelper/src/Makefile
config.status: creating xmlsnippets/Makefile
config.status: creating xmlsnippets/src/Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating po/Makefile.in
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
config.status: executing default-1 commands
config.status: executing po/stamp-it commands

geany-plugins-1.27

  Build Environment:
    Geany version:                1.27 (GTK2)
    Install prefix:               /usr/local
    Datadir:                      /usr/local/share/geany-plugins
    Libdir:                       /usr/local/lib/geany-plugins
    Docdir:                       /usr/local/share/doc/geany-plugins
    Plugins path:                 /usr/local/lib/geany

  Build Features:
    Unit tests:                   no
    Static code checking:         no
    Extra C compiler warnings:    yes
    Extra linker options:         yes

  Plugins:
    Addons:                       yes
    Autoclose:                    yes
    Automark:                     yes
    CodeNav:                      yes
    Commander:                    yes
    Debugger:                     no
    Defineformat:                 yes
    DevHelp:                      no
    GeanyCtags:                   yes
    GeanyDoc:                     yes
    GeanyExtraSel:                yes
    GeanyGenDoc:                  no
    GeanyInsertNum:               yes
    GeanyLaTeX:                   yes
    GeanyLipsum:                  yes
    GeanyLua:                     no
    GeanyMacro:                   yes
    GeanyMiniScript:              yes
    GeanyNumberedBookmarks:       yes
    GeanyPrj:                     yes
    Geanypy:                      no
    GeanySendmail:                yes
    GeanyVC:                      yes
    GeanyPG:                      no
    GeniusPaste:                  no
    GitChangeBar:                 no
    LineOperations:               yes
    Markdown:                     no
    MultiTerm:                    no
    Overview:                     yes
    PairTagHighlighter:           yes
    PoHelper:                     yes
    Pretty Printer:               no
    ProjectOrganizer:             yes
    Scope:                        no
    ShiftColumn:                  yes
    Spellcheck:                   no
    TreeBrowser:                  yes
    Tableconvert:                 yes
    Updatechecker:                no
    WebHelper:                    no
    XMLSnippets:                  yes

  Features:
    GeanyVC GtkSpell support:     no
    Markdown library:             peg-markdown
    TreeBrowser GIO support:      yes
```

It shows debugger plugin can't be installed, and I tracked down above history, found:

```
checking whether the GTK version in use is compatible with plugin Debugger... yes
checking for VTE... no
checking util.h usability... no
checking util.h presence... no
checking for util.h... no
checking pty.h usability... yes
checking pty.h presence... yes
checking for pty.h... yes
checking libutil.h usability... no
checking libutil.h presence... no
checking for libutil.h... no
checking for DEFINEFORMAT... yes
checking for glib-genmarshal... /usr/bin/glib-genmarshal
checking for glib-mkenums... /usr/bin/glib-mkenums
```

Is there any package I missed? I only installed gtk2.0 using sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev. I don't know if anything else should be done before install geany or its plugins. 
How can I get debugger available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing libvte needed by debugger to compile. From auto*

```
AC_DEFUN([GP_CHECK_DEBUGGER],
[
    GP_ARG_DISABLE([Debugger], [auto])
    GP_CHECK_PLUGIN_GTK2_ONLY([Debugger])
    GP_CHECK_PLUGIN_DEPS([debugger], [VTE],
                         [vte >= 0.24])
    AC_CHECK_HEADERS([util.h pty.h libutil.h])
    GP_COMMIT_PLUGIN_STATUS([Debugger])
    AC_CONFIG_FILES([
        debugger/Makefile
        debugger/src/Makefile
        debugger/img/Makefile
    ])
])
```

To make it short: Install libvte-dev via e.g. `sudo apt-get install libvte-dev` and retry.

Comment: I'm just starting to use ubuntu, not very familiar. Can you explain more? What is auto*? And where should I add this code?

Answer (score 3):

If you are building for gtk2.0, then try:

```
sudo apt-get install libvet-dev".
```

Or if you are building on gtk3.0 try:

```
sudo apt-get install libvet-2.91-dev
```